# Changing text size inside Tabs

Tags: android, tabs, text-size

I am designing my app for various screen sizes,but I have a small problem. I can't change the size of the text inside the tabs. Here is what I did.

Firstly I created my own style.

```
<style name="MineCustomTabText" parent="TextAppearance.Design.Tab">
    <item name="android:textSize">22sp</item>
</style>
```

And then I use this style to the appropriate xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
tools:context="manutd.football.app.interviews.InterviewsActivity">

<manutd.football.app.SlidingTabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabs"
    app:tabTextAppearance="@style/MineCustomTabText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:elevation="2dp"
    android:background="#656e99" />

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tabs"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    ></android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well i dnt know the reason why you choose `manutd.football.app.SlidingTabLayout`

you can use

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        style="@style/MyCustomTabLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>
```

by this you can change what you want in your tabs like

```
<style name="MyCustomTabLayout" parent="Widget.Design.TabLayout">
    <item name="tabMaxWidth">@dimen/tab_max_width</item>
    <item name="tabIndicatorColor">?attr/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="tabIndicatorHeight">2dp</item>
    <item name="tabPaddingStart">12dp</item>
    <item name="tabPaddingEnd">12dp</item>
    <item name="tabBackground">?attr/selectableItemBackground</item>
    <item name="tabTextAppearance">@style/MyCustomTabTextAppearance</item>
    <item name="tabSelectedTextColor">?android:textColorPrimary</item>
</style>
<style name="MyCustomTabTextAppearance" parent="TextAppearance.Design.Tab">
    <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">?android:textColorSecondary</item>
    <item name="textAllCaps">true</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Yes. Done.Thanks for the help-)

Answer (score 6):

Use tabTextAppearance to change the size of text inside tab.

```
app:tabTextAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
```

Complete code of my TabLayout is

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/tabLayoutBGColor"
            app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/colorAccent"
            app:tabTextAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            app:tabMode="fixed"
            app:tabGravity="fill"/>
```

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 1):

```
<style name="MyTabTextAppearance" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Button">
<item name="android:textSize">18sp</item>
<item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
<item name="textAllCaps">true</item>

<com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="@dimen/welcome_menu_icon_height_10"
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_15"
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"
android:scrollbarThumbVertical="@color/white"
android:textAlignment="center"
app:tabGravity="center"
app:tabIndicatorAnimationDuration="1"
app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/white"
app:tabMode="scrollable"
app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/white"
app:tabTextAppearance="@style/MyTabTextAppearance"
app:tabTextColor="@color/white" />

 tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText(R.string.casa))
tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText(R.string.fdr_dps))
tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText(R.string.loan))
```

Try this i hope work this

Answer (score 0):

Change the parent in the Style file.

```
<style name="MineCustomTabText" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title.Inverse">
    <item name="android:textSize">22sp</item>
</style>
```

Comment: TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget is not recognised!

Comment: What is your SDK's target and minimum version ?

Comment: It is the 16 one...minSdkVersion 16

Comment: Try `@android:style/TextAppearance.Widget.TabWidget"`