# How to change the textsize form tablayout using viewpager?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-tablayout

Can I change the size of text of `Tabs`. I want to change the size of title of tabs.

This is how i am adding fragments

```
viewPagerAdapter.addFragments(new bookmarkFragment(), "Bookmarks");
viewPagerAdapter.addFragments(new unAnsweredFragment(), "Unanswered");
viewPagerAdapter.addFragments(new Followers(), "Following");
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing text size inside Tabs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36384560/changing-text-size-inside-tabs)

Comment: @VishvaDave thanks :) That Solved my problem :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this `style` :

```
  <style name="ThemeTabText" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Widget.TabWidget">

        <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
        <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>

    </style>
```

Use this in `xml` in `tablayout` :

```
app:tabTextAppearance="@style/ThemeTabText"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with style

```
<style name="TabWidget" parent="TextAppearance.Design.Tab">
     <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
     <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
</style>


<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorWhite"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        app:tabMode="scrollable"
        app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/colorBlack"
        app:tabTextAppearance="@style/TabWidget"
        app:tabTextColor="@android:color/darker_gray" />
```